# When creating a list, the URL has ListName1

Tags: document-library

I have a new Blank Site with Publishing enabled. I create a document library called UIResources. When created, the URL is /Lsits/UIResources1. This is the first list I have created on this site. What is causing this to happen? Is there anything I can do to fix it? I ran a check from Powershell to see what lists (hidden or not) exist on the site. This is the only instance of a UIResources doc lib.

Comment: How do you create this list? Is this an OOTB list oor custom one? Can you provide some definition?

Answer (score 1):

Sir, due to your query/description I can't see that you really are encountering any problem! What is the strange about the Url? And what are you upp to fix?

Eliya Amanoeel

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing the library's url to UIResiources.

For changing url of a document library [see this post](http://www.dotnetindia.com/2011/02/changing-document-librarys-website-url-in-sharepoint-2010.html)